# Multiple Describe() in cgreen

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, tdd, bdd

I am using [cgreen](https://github.com/cgreen-devs/cgreen) to write tests for my C code, my question is:

**Short version:**
Is it possible to put more than one `Describe()` in one file?

**Long version:**
I have different test files, with their own `Describe()`, `BeforeEach()` and `AfterEach()`. Since in these files, I've used same module, I have to compile them together. [for preventing compiler from including the module more than once, I used this trick (include guard)

```c
#ifndef SOME_NAME
#define SOME_NAME

...

#endif
```

I also have a file which contains all my tests, let say `all_tests.c`. Now, I want to include my test files into `all_tests.c` and compile everything together, something like this:

```c
#include <cgreen/cgreen.h>

#include "./test1.c"
#include "./test2.c"

int main() {
    TestSuite *suite = create_test_suite();

    add_suite(suite, test1_tests());
    add_suite(suite, test2_tests());

    return run_test_suite(suite, create_text_reporter());
}
```

which leads to these errors:

```
error: redefinition of ‘setup’
error: redefinition of ‘teardown’
```

Obviously, because there is multiple definition of `Describe()`, `BeforeEach()` and `AfterEach()`. Well, I couldn't find a better idea, using recommended way of

```c
TestSuite *test1_tests();
TestSuite *test2_tests();
```

instead of including the files directly and assembling and compiling each test file separately and then linking all file together leads to this error:

```
multiple definition of `some_global_module'
```

which is expected, as in the linking state, there is multiple definition of the `some_global_module`. Just for being clear, the `test1.c` file looks like this (and also the `test2.c` file, just change `test1` to `test2` in the following code) :

```c
#include <cgreen/cgreen.h>

#include "./some_global_module.h"
#include "./some_other_module_i_want_to_test1.h"

Describe(test1);

BeforeEach(test1) {
    ...
}

AfterEach(test1) {
    ...
}

Ensure(test1, do_something) {
    ...
}

TestSuite *test1_tests() {
    TestSuite *suite = create_test_suite();
    add_test_with_context(suite, test1, do_something);
    return suite;
}
```

Any idea? Perhaps there is some compiler trick that I can use or an easier way to manage the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to include multiple `Describe()` in the same test file. And it should not be necessary.

You don't explain exactly how you assemble your tests/modules. There are a couple of options:

1. `#include` your module source in the test file - this is possible, but then you obviously can't link multiple test files together, you need to run them separately, since they define the same symbols for all in the module under test.
2. let the test "modules" use your module under test in the same fashion like other users of it would (`\#include` and calling the public interface). In this case your test files are modules as any other and should be linked together with a single instance of your module under test.
3. using the `cgreen-runner`. It loads shared libraries and discovers all tests in the library, alleviating you from the burdon of remembering to add each new test case to the suite.

Use #1 *only* if you are retrofitting tests to existing, un-testable, code, or *really* need to test the internals, like `static` functions.

#2 is pretty much standard and probably what you should do. In this case remove any `#include "some_global_module.c"` from your testfiles, like you have in your `test1.c`. Your `Makefile` should look something like:

```
all: all_tests

all_tests: all_tests.o some_global_module.o \
    test1.o some_global_module_under_test1.o \
    test2.o some_global_module_under_test2.o
```

So with `test1.c` and `test2.c` looking like you indicate, and the above Makefile content, I fail to see why you should get "multiple definition" at link time.

#3 is my favourite. Link everything into a shared object library (`.so` on Linux) and run `cgreen-runner` on it. Your `Makefile` should then look something like:

```
all: all_tests.so
    cgreen-runner ./$^ 

all_tests.so: some_global_module.o \
        test1.o some_global_module_under_test1.o \
        test2.o some_global_module_under_test2.o
    $(LINK) -shared -o $@ $^
```

NOTE: if your `some_global_module_under_test1` is dependent on a lot of other modules you either need to link them too, or mock them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas. This is an old question and in that time, it's a shame, but I should say that I didn't know the basics of the c compilers and it led me to the multiple definition error. Hope your answer helps others to set their test structure in a right way. cheers